# Differentiate normal text from text in quotes

Tags: javascript, html, regex, parsing

For a project that contains shortened JS code embedded onto a webpage, I want to know if text - which is from the value of a textarea on the webpage - is in quotes or not.

I already have this `RegExp`:

`/(?:^|")([^"]*)(?:$|")/`

It behaves weirdly when running `.exec()` on it via `about:blank` with something like `"\"console\" console \"asdf\" asdf \"consolea\" consolea"` (AKA only `"""` and `""`) , but I think it's because I don't really understand what the resulting data means nor am using it correctly or have the correct one.

What I'd want my code to do abstractly is this:

1. [Completed] Get the stringified value of the `textarea` on the page by its ID.
2. If `console` without any extra characters is included before the quoted text, get the quoted text minus its quotes (inside of a string, e.g. `"text"` instead of `"\"text\""`) just after it regardless of new-lines, provided that its starting quote comes before anything else after `console`.
3. Log the refined string to the console via `console.log`.

Code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Custom Programming Language</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <textarea id="code"></textarea>
        <br>
        <button id="run">Run!</button>
        <script>
            var code = document.getElementById("code").value.toString();
            
            // etc.
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have an algorithm in mind, just map it to a regular expression - let's break step 2 down:

1. "If console without any extra characters" - match `(?:^|\s+)console\s+` ("console" at line start or preceded by one or more spaces)
2. "before the quoted text minus its quotes" - match `\\?"(.+?)\\?"` (anything wrapped in quotes as a capturing group, quantify lazily to match the *first* closing quote). If you only allow escaped quotes, remove the `?` quantifier.
3. "regardless of new-lines" - set the `m` flag for multiline behavior.

All of the above combined yields us `/(?:^|\s+)console\s+\\?"(.+?)\\?"/gm`

```js
(() => {
  const code = document.querySelector("#code");
  const btn = document.querySelector("#run");
  
  code.value = `console \"test\"
        
        some other code here
  
    console \"another test\"
  `;
 
  const regex = /(?:^|\s+)console\s+\\?"(.+?)\\?"/gm;
  
  btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    const { value } = code;
  
    [...value.matchAll(regex)].forEach(m => console.log(m[1]));
  
  });

})();
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 50vh;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Custom Programming Language</title>
</head>

<body>
  <textarea id="code"></textarea>
  <br>
  <button id="run">Run!</button>
</body>

</html>
```